# Converting values in dictionary in to another dictionary using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, pytest, pymongo

I have a set of dictionaries with keys and values i need all the values as a separate dictionary

```
print(i)
O/P:
{'type':a,total:3}
{'type':b,total:2}
{'type':c,total:5}
{'type':d,total:6}
```

But now the required Output should like this...

```
{'a':3}
{'b':2}
{'c':5}
{'d':6}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
dictionaries = ({'type':'a','total':3},
            {'type':'b','total':2},
            {'type':'c','total':5},
            {'type':'d','total':6},)

for _dict in dictionaries:
    _type, total = _dict.values()
    print({_type : total})
```

Comment: its giving output like this

{'a': 3}
{'a': 3, 'b': 2}
{'a': 3, 'b': 2, 'c': 5}
{'a': 3, 'b': 2, 'c': 5, 'd': 6}

But i need like
{'a':3}
{'b':2}
{'c':5}
{'d':6}

Comment: Oh, you wanted separate, my bad. Check the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Given the following input:

```
dicts = [{'type':'a','total':3},
         {'type':'b','total':2},
         {'type':'c','total':5},
         {'type':'d','total':6}]
```

You can try using a list comprehension like this:

```
[{x:y for x,y in [d.values()]} for d in dicts]
```

Output:

```
[{'a': 3}, {'b': 2}, {'c': 5}, {'d': 6}]
```